# Fitted values of an Arimax model changing the X var

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, predictive-models

I estimate an arimax model
$y_t=a*y_{t-1} + b*x_t + e_t$

Where $x_t$ is a dummy with ones from a specific date and on. $(0,0,0,...,0,1,1,1,1,1)$

I estimate it with Arima instruction forecast package in R.
I would like to obtain fitted values of the ARIMAX model but considering what have had happended with no change  in the dummy. $(0,0,0,...,0,0,0,0,0,0)$
Which R-code could I use to obtain these values (a sort of counterfactual behaviour)?

Thanks

C

Answer (score 1):

just COMPUTE  yt=a∗yt−1 using excel. That will return fitted values/forecast values for periods 2 through t . Note the value of a is the estimate from your initial model where the predictor was (0,0,0,...,0,1,1,1,1,1)

Comment: Thank you, But indeed the question was related to how to manage forecast/predict instruction in R to obtain the prediction with a changed X.

Comment: Just write a script in R instead of excel to do the computation.